# How can I render animation parts separately?

Tags: rendering

I want to render an animation with three parts:

1. background
2. cloud
3. perfume bottle

The cloud was made using volume, so it is important that the perfume bottle goes through the cloud and while moving is behind the cloud sometimes.

I want to do it so it renders faster than all combined.

I have been trying to turn off the ray visibility of the camera of the certain objects, and combine it but it is losing this effect when the bottle is behind the cloud.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Did you try Compositor?
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLp90cx0wSyKawSPe_26RWZ40A0sFL15Xe

Comment: @TergTurry will it work with animation?

Comment: Yes, it will. That's how VFX work.

Comment: I will try - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### You can use View Layers.

Create new View Layers with the little button in the upper-right corner of Blender, to the right of where it says View Layer.

Use the dropdown to switch between View Layers.

Place the things you want on their own layers into collections. Uncheck the collections on the layers where you don't want to see them.

Also make sure to turn on Transparent under Film in the Cycles settings to get a clear background (if you want.)

Use the Compositor to layer together your rendered layers.

**(For your case, however, I would make sure the cloud and bottle stay on the same layer. Rendering will be faster that way, and the results will be more realistic.)**

Comment: Thank you, I will try it :)